# Best way to notify users on Salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, event, notification

So I have an app/script that does a a bunch of data synchronizations from our own database to a salesforce database. I'm wondering what's the best way to notify users of an event on their salesforce page?

Is there a specific API that allows me to do this? I looked at the Streaming API, but that seems like it sends push notifications from salesforce -> app, when I want the other way around. 
Or is there an option that notify users when a field has changed? That way I can create a custom field for the object and notify users by updating that field?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Chatter Feed Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_Chatter)?

Comment: I checked it out, and I may need something that's more distinct than a feed update. I may go with the route of creating a new task for the user, since usually the user would need to act on these notifications.